# Join multiple csv files from a folder into a single csv python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

i have around 100 csv files in a folder.

```
/path/to/directory/*.csv
 it has files abc.csv,dsf.csv,rgfb.csv.....etc
```

a view of csv file.

```
182 a   1   4   242 52450
182 a   1   2   242 7176
182 c   1   1   242 7176
182 c   1   1   242 7410
```

i want to take all this csv from the directory and make it in one csv.
There are no column names, but all the csv has same no of columns(i.e 5), and i want to join all csv, and put it in pandas dataframe and give column names
as

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
data  data  data  data  data
...   ...    ...   ...   ...
```

what i tried was.

```
import os
csv_list = []
for root, dirs,files in os.walk("path/to/directory", topdown=True):
for name in files:
    csv_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

i got the list of csv

then i did

```
import pandas as pd
combined_csv = pd.append( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_list ] )
```

but it is appending horizontally and not vertically.

Also i have to give column names to 'combined_csv' 
is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `axis=1` if need append vertically:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in csv_list ], axis=1)
```

And if need append horizontally is default parameter `axis=0` which can be omit:

```
import pandas as pd
combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in csv_list ], ignore_index=True)
```

If need set column names use parameter `names`:

```
names = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names = names) for f in csv_list ],
                           ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: check edit , i have a view of my csv file, and your answer is not working. i am getting `5 rows × 66 columns`  as i tried it for 11 csv files

Comment: 1csv has 5 coulmns and while putting it to dataframe it is adding index, so 6 columns and concatenating 11 csv files it is giving me 11x6 = 66 columns

Comment: I think I see problem, need parameter `header=None`

Comment: still, after adding parameter and running `combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in csv_list ], axis=1)` i am getting 5 rows × 66 columns

Comment: hmmm, maybe need `combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in csv_list ])`

Comment: axis=0 is doing the trick, any way to add new column's other than renaming columns at the end?

Comment: sure, five me a sec.

Comment: thank you very much. I check my old answers, there are not accepted, there is some problem or you only forget?

Comment: sir, a little issue, when i am joining, `index` is coming as a column in dataframe.  columns = `index,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,`

Comment: sorry, ther is important one thing - `ignore_index=True` for avoid duplicates.

Comment: combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names = names,ignore_index=True) for f in csv_list ]) not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131329/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-jezrael).